# Select limited data row from filtered data

Tags: vba, excel

I have 70,000 rows of data in an Excel sheet. After applying a filter, the total number of visible rows becomes 40,000. Now I would like to select and copy the first 15,000 visible rows only.

Comment: You really need to edit this question for clarity.

Comment: thanks for quick response
in simple way - i just want to copy the 1st 15000 rows from filtered data.

Comment: in simple way - i just want to copy the 1st 15000 visible* rows from filtered data.

Comment: I believe something like Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy is what you want.

Comment: After following @MatthewD's suggestion and pasting to a new sheet, delete rows after 15000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you. I would suggest setting it up to run on a keyboard shortcut.

```
Const limit As Integer = 15000 

Sub GrabFiltered()
    Dim r As Range
    Dim lr As Range
    Dim tr As Range
    Dim rr As Range
    Dim br As Range
    Dim table As Range
    Dim rows As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim ct As Integer
    Dim offset As Integer

    Set r = Selection.Cells(1, 1)
    If r.End(xlToLeft).Cells(1, 1).FormulaR1C1 <> "" Then
        Set lr = r.End(xlToLeft).Cells(1, 1)
    Else
        Set lr = r
    End If
    If lr.End(xlUp).Cells(1, 1).FormulaR1C1 <> "" Then
        Set tr = lr.End(xlUp).Cells(1, 1)
    Else
        Set tr = lr
    End If
    If r.End(xlToRight).Cells(1, 1).FormulaR1C1 <> "" Then
        Set rr = r.End(xlToRight).Cells(1, 1)
    Else
        Set rr = r
    End If
    rr.Select
    If rr.End(xlDown).Cells(1, 1).FormulaR1C1 <> "" Then
        Set br = rr.End(xlDown).Cells(1, 1)
    Else
        Set br = r
    End If

    Set table = Range(tr, br)

    'count the number of rows that are visible
    rows = 0
    For i = 1 To table.rows.Count
        If table.Cells(i, 1).Height <> 0 Then
            rows = rows + 1
        End If
    Next

    'limit the number of rows to copy
    If rows > limit Then
        offset = rows - limit
        i = 1
        ct = 1
        While i <> offset
            If br.offset(-ct, 0).Height <> 0 Then
                i = i + 1
            End If
            ct = ct + 1
        Wend
        Set br = br.offset(-ct, 0)
        Set table = Range(tr, br)
    End If

    table.Copy
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. Since this worked for you, please click the checkmark next to the answer. This indicates to the community that you found the answer acceptable and gives both you and I additional reputation points.